# Why do I get a negative value when using timer MACRO based on clock()?

Tags: c++, c, timer, macros, clock

The macro is like this:

```
#define MAX 10000000
#define CNT 1000000
#define TIMER_INIT             \
    clock_t starttime, endtime;    \
#define TIMER(txt, process)                     \
    starttime = clock();                        \
    process;                            \
    endtime = clock();                      \
    printf("%-20s %20ld\n",                     \
           txt, (endtime - starttime))
```

The main codes is like this:

```
char vector2[CNT/8 + 1];

TIMER(  "bitsort",
        for(i = 0; i < CNT; ++i)
            set1(rand() % MAX, vector2));
```

And the set1 function is like this:

```
void set1(int pos, char* vector)        /* set the position to 1 */
{
    vector[pos/8] |= (0x1 << pos%8);
}
```

When I execute the program, the output looks like this..

```
bitsort                -36035411302143896
```

Even if I cast the difference to `unsigned int` like this, it still doesn't work:

```
#define TIMER(txt, process)                     \
    starttime = clock();                        \
    process;                            \
    endtime = clock();                      \
    printf("%-20s %20d\n",                      \
           txt, (unsigned int)(endtime - starttime))
```

Output is `bitsort                         -16766097`

I tried to modify `%ld` to `%d`, but it doesn't work.

But if I don't use `for` in the parameter, like this:

```
TIMER("bitsort", set1(rand() % MAX,vector2));
```

The `TIMER` works perfectly and gives me a reasonable result..

Does anyone have idea about what's wrong with my code? Is it caused by macro or by `clock()` function? Thanks!

Comment: try using %d again, but cast them to an unsigned int. Instead of: (endtime - starttime), try (unsigned int)(endtime - starttime) and tell us what happens.

Comment: @MMavipc The output is still a negative number, quite strange.

Comment: Are you using `TIMER_INIT`? Your code doesn't show it...

Comment: @nneonneo Yes, I used `TIMER_INIT` at the beginning of the `main()` function

Comment: And is there really a \ on the last line of `TIMER_INIT`?

Comment: Actually, I think you might be smashing your stack. Can you show what `MAX` and `CNT` are? Observe that if `MAX` is bigger than `CNT` you will have a buffer overflow which will invalidate `endtime`, `starttime`, or both.

Comment: -1 for making printf invoke undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found your issue:

Look at this documentation http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/

Notice something about %d and %i? **Signed** decimal integer

You must use %u or %lu because clock_t is unsigned, and an unsigned int is also obviously unsigned.

Edit: This was only half of the problem, the other half was that he was **destroying his stack(MAX is larger than CNT)** in the bitsort function, thanks to @nneonneo in the chat for finding that.

Comment: I don't think so, when I modify `%d` to `%u`, the result is obvious wrong. (More than 4000 seconds if I use print(..., (end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC)). @MMavipc

Comment: are you still casting it to an unsigned int?

Comment: Yes,  My code is :printf("%lu\n",      \
        (unsigned int)(endtime - starttime)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC)

Comment: Well here's your problem %lu is expecting an unsigned long, and you're giving it an unsigned int. They have two different sizes. try just using %u alone.

Comment: I tried `%u`, but the result is still 4000+ seconds.. I think the problem may be caused by the `for` statement passed into the MACRO as it works perfectly when I use `TIMER(set1(rand() % MAX,vector2));` But I've no idea why I can't use `for` in the parameter

Comment: Use this printf statement: printf("%-20s %20lu\n",                      
           txt, (endtime - starttime))

Comment: This gives me a result of `
18410708662407`...

Comment: @Firegun hmm try printf("%lu %lu\n", endtime, starttime); just for debugging purposes

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17637/discussion-between-mmavipc-and-firegun)

Comment: Don't use cplusplus.com. It's known to contain a lot of errors.